# Error trying to install Oracle database on Docker Windows container

Tags: windows, oracle, docker, windows-container

I need to create a Docker Windows container with an Oracle database 18c on it.

I followed this tutorial from Oracle (page 19 to 26) : https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/tech-info/oow18windowscontainers-5212844.pdf

When I execute the setup using a response file with this command :

```
RUN c:\data\db_home\setup.bat -silent -noconfig -noConsole -ignorePrereq -J"-
Doracle.install.db.validate.supportedOSCheck=false" -responseFile c:\data\db.rsp
```

I get the following error :

```
[FATAL] PRVG-1901 : failed to setup CVU remote execution framework directory 
"C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\InstallActions2020-07-17_01-18-
31PM\CVU_18.0.0.0.0_ContainerAdministrator\" on nodes "975ef812cf39" Please select a different work 
area for the framework 975ef812cf39 : PRKN-1014 : Failed to execute remote command
"C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\InstallActions2020-07-17_01-18-
31PM\CVU_18.0.0.0.0_ContainerAdministrator\\exectask.exe" on node "975ef812cf39".Failed during 
connecting to service 975ef812cf39 : Failed during connecting to service
```

Here's my configuration :

- Windows 10 Pro build 2004
- Docker Desktop version 2.3.03

Container :

- Windows server-core build 2004
- Oracle Database 18c

I've been doing tests for several days but I still haven't been able to solve this problem...

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Nobody seems to be running Oracle on Docker Windows containers.

Answer (score 1):

Normally the error PRVG-1901 is related with a privilege issue.

- Run the console as administrator
- Check whether a `REG DWORD` named `AutoShareWks` exists (in registry `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters`). It did not. But if it would, make sure that the value is set to `1` and restart.
- Stopped the `OracleRemExecServiceV2` service

In my case, running console as administrator fixed the issue.

Comment: I also noticed that this was due to a lack of permission but the setup.bat runs inside my Windows server Core container and I don't know any way to run a console as an administrator in a container. (On my physical pc I have of course run the command prompt in admin mode but I don't think this is the case on the container).

Answer (score 0):

You can just take ready docker images here:
https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleDatabase

Comment: From what I've seen these DockerFile uses an "oraclelinux" for their image. I can't do that since I'm using Windows containers.

Comment: @Sultaker I successfully started oracle linux image with Oracle 18 and 19 on WIndows 10

Comment: I know that you can run linux on containers on Windows 10 but in addition to having Windows 10 on my host, in Docker I use Windows containers (you can switch between windows and linux containers in docker) and in Windows container mode I can't install a linux container I get an error which is normal.

In short, I did not find a solution so I switched my Docker to Linux container mode and installed Oracle with the github mentioned. Thanks anyway for your help

Comment: You can install wls2 and use native Linux docker on windows